# Conditional rendering template on Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a simple situation that I want to render cart-badge based on window width value but it always show the last one even though windowWidth does change the value. Please advise me what to do !

```
    <template v-if="windowWidth>=1024">
                        <div class="nav-user-account"> {{windowWidth}}      
                            <div class="nav-cart nav-cart-box">                                
                                <a href="/cart" rel="nofollow"><span class="text hidden-sm">Cart</span></a>
                                <span class="cart-number" id="nav-cart-num">{{cartItemCount}}</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </template>
    <template v-if="windowWidth<1024">
                        <a href="#" style="color:#ff6a00" class="icon-cart">
{{windowWidth}} 
                            <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            <span class="cart-num">2</span>
                        </a>
                    </template>
                    <script>
                        import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
                        export default {
                            data() {
                                return {
                                    windowWidth: window.innerWidth,

                                }
                            },
                            computed: {
                                ...mapGetters('cart', {
                                    cartItemCount: 'getShoppingCartItemsCount'
                                })
                            },

                            mounted() {
                                this.$nextTick(() => {
                                    window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
                                        this.windowWidth= window.innerWidth
                                    });
                                })
                            },
                        }
                    </script>
```

UPDATED: as Tony19 pointed out, i need a master template outside of these 2 template.

```
<template>
    <div>
<template v-if="windowWidth>=1024">...</template>
<template v-else></template>
</div>
</template>
```

Comment: what's the problem?

Comment: sorry not to input that. My problem is it always render the last template no matter what window width changes.

Comment: Seems to work fine in this [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/kn9lr7207?module=src/components/ShoppingCart.vue). Can you modify the demo to match your use case?